# What can a hacker do with your .ENV file?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I understand most of mysql deny external connections. So, let's say my .env file is exposed and a hacker manages to get it. What can they do with its information?

Comment: Stack Overflow isn’t really the place to ask “what if” questions.

Comment: It depends really. The .env file often contains like every single critical config value of your system: connection details of your database and mail servers, your encryption key, access tokens to publicly exposed APIs, ... It would be really bad if that would happen.

Comment: I'm not going to post a proper answer either as I don't think its the right place to do it, but you can research it, Hosting providers as much as the details are a problem and there are many ways to skin a cat as they say. A .env holds far more than db connections, quite commonly your encyption key, email account details, stripe access tokens etc etc etc.  Its not a place you want to be going.  And if you expose your .env, what are you doing in Laravel as a root user on the server for example, what other backdoor can a hacker use?

Answer (score 2):

**Database**: the hacker can use the DB credentials and read/write/remove data from your database.

**Client's Credentails**: after the DB login, with the **ENV_KEY** they can decrpt password of all the users. Basically login in and violate the privacy.

**Payment Gateway**: If using any payment gateway then those key + secret is also exposed. Not sure what they would use this for. I mean, they would rather receive payments on their payment account.

**Clone**: All those years of hard work will be copied in seconds. (Saw it on **Silicon Valley**)

**Even worse**, your clients information is in their hands now. They can **sell/share** that & because of that you are liable for that breach.

---

Basically whatever good or bad you can do with your project, the hacker can do much more damage because he/she will not be **responsible** for his/her actions. You will be.

Comment: The `APP_KEY` is not used to "decrypt" password, that's a common misconception. Passwords are **hashed** and not encrypted. The salt used to hash the password differs for each password hashed and the `APP_KEY` is not used in any way for this.

Comment: But even if they have my DB credentials, they wouldn't be able to connect because basically every mysql blocks external connections. Is there something am I missing?

Comment: It depends how they got hold of your .env. If they have server access they can access your database, even if it's behind a firewall or disallows connections from the outside, but if they only have a copy of the .env, by an administrator or a leaked repo for example, they can only access publicly available services. The first case would obviously be a nightmare.